# unable to setup C++ environment with sublime text and mingw

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, mingw

I am trying to set up sublime text with mingw.
I have add the path as C:\mingw\bin
I have add the build system with the following code:

```
{
    "cmd" : "g++ $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && ${file_base_name}",
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

However I got a compiler error when running any code:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: g++  -o  && ]
[dir: C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\Quaxie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

I have been googling for the past 4 hours and tried with multiple build codes and non of the worked. I cant really figure out which part went wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is on windows 10

Comment: Think it's just s single `&` to chain commands on Windows,`&&` is bash

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `"cmd"` to `"shell_cmd"` and put curly braces around `file_name` and `file_path`. Also, adding a `"file_regex"` key and value will assist you in locating any errors in the build.

```json
{
    "shell_cmd" : "g++ ${file_name} -o ${file_base_name} && ${file_base_name}",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir" : "${file_path}"
}
```